# How do I use a nested IF(AND) in an Excel array formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

How do I get a nested 'AND' to work inside 'IF' in an array formula?

I reduced my problem to the following example:
[image: Excel spreadsheet showing array formula with nested AND]
*Note: the above image has been updated to included the array formula curly braces*

At the top right, we have the search criteria in L3 ("color") and L4 ("shape"). At the left, column D contains working match formulas for both color and shape in the list of items. The first table shows the match formula working properly without using an array formula.

The second table shows an array formula that matches the color.

The third table shows an array formula that matches the shape.

On the right is my attempt to use both criteria in an array formula, by combining them with AND.

IF the value in the color column matches the color criteria (L3) and the value in the shape column matches the shape criteria (L4), then I want to see "MATCH!".

I did find a workaround: concatenate the values and criteria, and then match them inside a single IF. I feel like there should be a Better Way... like if AND worked as expected!

**Note:**
Many of the answers below work correctly but not as array formulas, which is specifically what this question is about. I looked at my original question and realized I forgot to show the curly braces in the array formula examples. I have fixed the image to show them. Sorry for the confusion.

The key to answering these questions is to write something that works as an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-array-formula-HP005200020.aspx), which is entered by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing the formula into a cell. Excel will automaically add the curly braces to indicate that it's an array formula.

Comment: @simoco's answer is correct. Because `and` accepts arrays as arguments and returns a single value ("Are all of these true?") it isn't applied to each element separately, the way a function (such as `if`) accepting only single values is. Different contexts, different ways to "work as expected." :-) Multiplying arrays (implicitly TRUE->1, FALSE->0) is the array equivalent of `and` (returns non-zero if none is zero), and adding (non-negative) arrays is the array equivalent of `or` (returns non-zero if any is non-zero).

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan, simoco's answer works but not in an array formula. I have updated the original question so it's clearer what I'm asking for. I noticed the image didn't show the curly braces, so maybe it was unclear. BernardSaucier's answer does work in curly braces so it answers the questions. There may be other/better solutions that are more scalable to longer arguments to AND().

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan I made a mistake in my worksheet -- actually simoco's answer works great!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use next **array** formula:

```
=IF(($J$16:$J$22=$L$3)*($K$16:$K$22=$L$4),"MATCH!","-")
```

here is a [link](http://dropbox.com/s/7m1amdjfxo4lzq8/Simoco_Test.xlsx) to the test workbook.

Comment: This isn't using IF as an array formula, and this solution breaks if an array formula is used. I just realized my original question doesn't show the array formula curly braces, so maybe that's confusing the question. I will fix it.

Comment: It's exactly array formula and it works well for me. If you select L16:L22 range and with selected range enter the formula in the formula bar, and them press CTRL+SHEET+ENTER - you'd get the result you need (and curly brackets will apear). I've tested formula many times

Comment: Using the * operator does not make it an array formula (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-array-formula-HP005200020.aspx)

Comment: `and this solution breaks if an array formula is used` - How it breaks??? Have you really tried it to use like array function? And what are you going to do if you'd have 10 criteries (not 2) - are you going to use 10 nested `IF`'s??

Comment: It just gives a MATCH result for everything. Did you try it as an array formula? Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/QMU41eM

Comment: Hm..here is my example workbook..try it, please. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7m1amdjfxo4lzq8/Simoco_Test.xlsx

Comment: Thanks. Your worksheet works perfectly fine, and the formula is entered as an array formula. We have the same formulas entered, but in my test worksheet it doesn't work. Weird!

Comment: Got it to work; I didn't have all the cells selected when I pressed SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER. Could you edit your answer to include the link to your workbook? SO isn't letting me change my vote without the answer being edited.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed my accepted answer to this one, since it's scalable to more criteria.

Comment: Indeed my solution was very hard to scale! +1 to this excellent alternative.

Comment: This is so elegant and excellent solution. and for OR operations, use + instead of * . POI: Array formulas on a mac: shift-command-enter

Answer (score 6):

You can nest an IF inside the `value of true` of an `IF` to achieve an `IF something AND somethingelse`. For example :

```
=IF(A1="something", IF(A2="somethingelse", "A1 is something and A2 is somethingelse", "A1 is something but A2 is not something else"), "A1 is nothing and A2 is nothingelse")
```

**Some extra details on trying this code out :** write "something" (without quotes) in A1, and "somethingelse" in A2, put that formula inside any other cell of that sheet. Play around with those values to see where you land in the nested IFs.

Comment: This works great! The specific solution in my question is `{=IF($J16:$J22=$L$3,IF($K16:$K22=$L$4,"MATCH","-"),"-")}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these two ways instead of AND: putting "*" between the conditions and the second way is using nested Ifs. for example one of these:

```
=IF(($J$16:$J$22=$L$3)*($K$16:$K$22=$L$4),"MATCH!","-")
```

or

```
=IF($J$16:$J$22=$L$3, if($K$16:$K$22=$L$4,"MATCH!","-"))
```

Logically For using OR or XOR you have to put ()+() or - accordingly. Ididn't test them now.

Regards,
M