# Excel: How to divide each item in sumifs array formula by set value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet which looks like this:

```
A       B           C                 D              E
Status  payed by    involved          # of involved  price
payed   Felix       Felix, Peter            2        22,00 €
open    Timothy     Felix, Peter, Chelsea   3        90,00 €
open    Peter       Peter, Timothy          2        2,40 €
open    Chelsea     Chelsea, Felix          2        7,00 €
```

Now, I want a formula which calculates how much each person has to pay to come out equal, while only paying for things in which said person was involved in.
Currently, I do the following:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E13; B2:B13; "*Peter*"; A2:A13; "open")
```

To calculate how much each person already paid.
Then, I want to calculate how much each person has to pay.
My "dream formula" for that would be:

```
{=SUMIFS(E2:E13/D2:D13; A2:A13; "open"; C2:C13; "*Peter*")}
```

So that each items gets split by the number of people involved and the split part then added to each persons total. The problem is, such an array formula does not exist and is not valid.

How can I correct that? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will sum up the price per involved person where Status is open and involved contains Peter

```
=SUM(IF(($A$2:$A$5="open") * (ISERROR(FIND("Peter", $C$2:$C$5)) = FALSE), $E$2:$E$5 / $D$2:$D$5, 0))
```

(It's an array formula so CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER)

FYI I referenced SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057012/how-do-i-use-a-nested-ifand-in-an-excel-array-formula), could be worth a read

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT()`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E2:E13/D2:D13)*(A2:A13 = "OPEN")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Peter";C2:C13))))
```