# Excel - array formula - count days in range of weeks

Tags: excel, array-formulas

[image]

I am trying to get an Excel Array Formula working.

There is a list o weeks - each has a start date and an end date. There is a number of GRP in every week.

I want to SUM all GRP (proportionally) from all weeks that are between specific days.

For one week is easy

```
=IF(AND(B2>=$A4;B1<=$A5);IF(B1<$A4;B2-$A4+1;IF(B2>$A5;$A5-B1+1;B2-B1+1));0)/(B2-B1+1)*B3
```

Based on this formula I created an array formula, which doesn't work :(

```
{=SUM(IF(AND(B2:H2>=$A4;B1:H1<=$A5);IF(B1:H1<$A4;B2:H2-$A4+1;IF(B2:H2>$A5;$A5-B1:H1+1;B2:H2-B1:H1+1));0)/(B2:H2-B1:H1+1)*B3:H3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Post found on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057012/how-do-i-use-a-nested-ifand-in-an-excel-array-formula)

Need to multiply 2 Ranges (arrays) instead of using AND :)

```
{=SUM(IF((B2:H2>=$A4)*(B1:H1<=$A5);JEŻELI(B1:H1<$A4;B2:H2-$A4+1;JEŻELI(B2:H2>$A5;$A5-B1:H1+1;B2:H2-B1:H1+1));0)/(B2:H2-B1:H1+1)*B3:H3)}
```