# Using Office365 Excel array formulas, how to determine each person's min and max?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, office365, array-formulas

Given the below test data.  How can the array formula be structured to produce the desired results?

```
=LET(item,G4,name,A4:A7,data,C4:E15,
    names, CHOOSECOLS(data,1),
    items, CHOOSECOLS(data,2),
    cnt,   CHOOSECOLS(data,3),
    mn,    MIN(IF(AND(name=names,item=items,cnt>0),cnt,FALSE)),
    mx,    MAX(IF(AND(name=names,item=items,cnt>0),cnt,FALSE)),
if(and(not(mn),not(mx)),"None",mn&" : "&mx) )
```

Boat is entered in the Show column, so the result should be related to boats.  If the green cell is changed to Car, then the results should only show cars, etc...

[image]

The formula is in cell I4 and produces `#N/A`.  I tried some other similar formulas but no luck so far.

Comment: perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21057012/4961700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you could try using `MAP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `I4`

```
=LET(x,FILTER(HSTACK(C4:C15,E4:E15),G4=D4:D15),
HSTACK(A4:A7,MAP(A4:A7,LAMBDA(m,
LET(y,FILTER(INDEX(x,,2),ISNUMBER(XMATCH(INDEX(x,,1),m)),0),
IF(OR(MIN(y),MAX(y)),MIN(y)&" : "&MAX(y),"None"))))))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of alternatives you can use `MINIFS`, `MAXIFS` both functions return `0` if there is no match for the criteria, if we can assume `0` is not a valid count, then we can have this simple approach (*formula 1*):

```
=LET(A,A2:A5, B,B2:B13,C,C2:C13, D,D2:D13, lk,F2, z,MAP(A,LAMBDA(x,
 MINIFS(D,B,x,C,lk) &":"& MAXIFS(D,B,x,C,lk))), HSTACK(A,IF(z="0:0", "None",z)))
```

**Note**: You can avoid the `MAP` function as follows (*formula 2*):

```
=LET(A,A2:A5, AA,TOROW(A), B,B2:B13, C,C2:C13, D,D2:D13, lk,F2, z,TOCOL(
 MINIFS(D,B,AA,C,lk) &":"& MAXIFS(D,B,AA,C,lk)),HSTACK(A,IF(z="0:0", "None",z)))
```

If `0` is a valid count, then there is no way to distinguish the case of names with boat value with `0` count and names with no boats. To consider `0` as a valid count, we need to take a different approach. We cannot use `MAXIFS/MINIFS` because they are [RACON function](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions) and we need to filter first, i.e. the input would be an array and not a range (*formula 3*):

```
=LET(A,A2:A5, B,B2:B13,C,C2:C13, D,D2:D13, lk,F2, x, MAP(A,LAMBDA(w, LET(
 f,FILTER(D,(B=w)*(C=lk), ""),MIN(f) &":"& MAX(f)))),HSTACK(A,IFERROR(x,"None")))
```

Using the third input argument of `FILTER` with a text value, for the case of not matching criteria `MAX/MIN` returns `#VALUE!`, so now we have a way to distinguish this case. Finally using `IFERROR` transforms it to `"None"`.

Here is the output using *formula 1*:
[image: output]

The Lookup Names can be also obtained via `UNIQUE(B)`, we keep it that way, because the sorting is different.